# Get the value of URL Parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the parameters from a URL using Swift. Let's say I have the following URL:

```
http://mysite3994.com?test1=blah&test2=blahblah
```

How can I get the values of test1 and test2?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

You can use the below code to get the param

```
func getQueryStringParameter(url: String, param: String) -> String? {
  guard let url = URLComponents(string: url) else { return nil }
  return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
}
```

Call the method like `let test1 = getQueryStringParameter(url, param: "test1")`

**Other method with extension:**

```
extension URL {
    public var queryParameters: [String: String]? {
        guard
            let components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
            let queryItems = components.queryItems else { return nil }
        return queryItems.reduce(into: [String: String]()) { (result, item) in
            result[item.name] = item.value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why cast to `NSURLQueryItem`? Some unnecessary

Comment: Also, it's better to use `first(where:)` instead of `filter(_:)` then `first`. It stops as soon as it finds the first match, so it's much faster. Plus it saves an array allocation

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the suggestion you can edit the answer for making it more better.

Comment: I receive this error "Value of type 'NSURLComponenets' has no member 'first'"

Comment: @user2423476 Check now I have tested in playground with swift 3.

Comment: @Matian2049 There's a library called "EZSwiftExtensions" you can use it.

Comment: corrected calling method is:
----
let test1 = getQueryStringParameter(url: url, param: "test1")

Answer (score 109):

**Step 1:** Create URL extension

```
extension URL {
    func valueOf(_ queryParameterName: String) -> String? {
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) else { return nil }
        return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == queryParameterName })?.value
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** How to use the extension

```
let newURL = URL(string: "http://mysite3994.com?test1=blah&test2=blahblah")!

newURL.valueOf("test1") // Output i.e "blah"
newURL.valueOf("test2") // Output i.e "blahblah"
```

Answer (score 37):

I also made a URL extension, but put the query param lookup into a subscript.

```
extension URL {
    subscript(queryParam:String) -> String? {
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) else { return nil }
        return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == queryParam })?.value
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://some-website.com/documents/127/?referrer=147&mode=open")!

let referrer = url["referrer"]  // "147"
let mode     = url["mode"]      // "open"
```

Comment: You can use like this, 

            let urlString = URL(string: url.absoluteString)!
            guard let userName = urlString.valueOf("userName"),
                let code     = urlString.valueOf("code"),
                let userId = urlString.valueOf("userName") else {
                    return false
            }
            
            print("Details: \(urlString)")
            print("userName: \(userName)")
            print("code: \(code)")
            print("userId: \(userId)")

Comment: @Mehul why would you create an URL from another URL `let urlString = URL(string: url.absoluteString)!` is pointless. Btw `URL` has no `valueOf` method.

Comment: This should return an Array unless you are completely sure that each Query Item has a unique name.

Answer (score 13):

Another way of doing this is to create an extension on URL to return the components, and then create an extension on [URLQueryItem] to retrieve the value from the queryItems.

```
extension URL {
    var components: URLComponents? {
        return URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
    }
}

extension Array where Iterator.Element == URLQueryItem {
    subscript(_ key: String) -> String? {
        return first(where: { $0.name == key })?.value
    }
}
```

And this is an example of how this could be used:

```
if let urlComponents = URL(string: "http://mysite3994.com?test1=blah&test2=blahblah")?.components,
    let test1Value = urlComponents.queryItems?["test1"] {
    print(test1Value)
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It appears that none of existing answers work when the link leads to a web site created on Angular. This is because Angular's paths often include a `#` (hash) symbol in all links, which results in `url.queryItems` always returning nil.

If a link looks like this: `http://example.com/path/#/morepath/aaa?test1=blah&test2=blahblah`

Then the parameters can only be obtained from `url.fragment`. With some additional parsing logic added to @Matt's extension, a more universal code would look like this:

```
extension URL {
    subscript(queryParam: String) -> String? {
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) else { return nil }
        if let parameters = url.queryItems {
            return parameters.first(where: { $0.name == queryParam })?.value
        } else if let paramPairs = url.fragment?.components(separatedBy: "?").last?.components(separatedBy: "&") {
            for pair in paramPairs where pair.contains(queryParam) {
                return pair.components(separatedBy: "=").last
            }
            return nil
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Usage remains same:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/path/#/morepath/aaa?test1=blah&test2=blahblah")!

let referrer = url["test1"]  // "blah"
let mode     = url["test2"]  // "blahblah"
```

Comment: You saved my day by mentioning url.fragment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in KMP ios Module

```
actual fun getQueryParameter(url:String,name: String): String?{

    val uri= NSURLComponents(string = url)

    var queryValue:String?=null

    uri.queryItems?.let {
        for (i in it){
            val item= i as NSURLQueryItem
            if (item.name==name)
            {
                queryValue=item.value
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return queryValue

}
```