# Find specific character from URL Link

Tags: swift, string, url, double, latitude-longitude

How can I find out specific character from URL String variable using Swift 3? 
[image: A URL is visible photo, i want to get the value out of the URL user_lati,user_long,destination_lat,destinaton_long]

i want to get the value out of the URLlink(image is given) user_lati,user_long,destination_lat,destinaton_long and save it.

Can any one give me the solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value of URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421686/get-the-value-of-url-parameters)

Comment: can u please give me proper explanation vadim ?

Comment: The other question that I have linked above shows you how to get these values from a URL

Comment: please read my question properly my requirement is diffrent, and your answer is totally diffrnt

Comment: you want to find position of ? character?

Comment: yes i want to have a character - scriptable

Comment: Why don't you give a precise example of the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have given a couple of examples below. You should really check the documentation for [String](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string), [URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) and [Collections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection)

```
let urlString = "https://www.example.com/search?q=test&user=john"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

print(url.query) // q=test&user=john
print(urlString.index(of: "?")?.encodedOffset) // 30 - index of ?
print(url.absoluteString.index(of: "?")?.encodedOffset) // same as above
```