# How to get the value of url parameter using swift 4.1

Tags: ios, json, swift, object, swift4.1

I am trying to get parameters for urls and I try to get only the date not time the URL.

```
http://aa.no-ip.biz:8001/hf_tracker/api/history.php?accesskey=12345&Vehilce=1618&FromDate=2018-05-10 13:11&ToDate=2018-05-14 12:11
```

Code:

```
extension URL {
    func valueOf(_ queryParameterName: String) -> String? { 
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) else { 
              return nil 
        } 

        return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == queryParameterName})?.value 
    } 
}
    
    let newURL = URL(string: "assetlinkasia.no-ip.biz:8001/hf_tracker/api/…)! 
    newURL.valueOf("toDate") 
    newURL.valueOf("fromDate")
```

How can I only get the date and not time?

Comment: show us your code, what you have tried

Comment: post relevant code for easy understanding @Rehan Meo

Comment: extension URL {
    func valueOf(_ queryParamaterName: String) -> String? {
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) else { return nil }
        return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == queryParamaterName })?.value
    }
}


let newURL = URL(string: "http://assetlinkasia.no-ip.biz:8001/hf_tracker/api/history.php?accesskey=12345&Vehilce=1618&FromDate=2018-05-10%2013:11&ToDate=2018-05-14%2012:11")!

newURL.valueOf("toDate") 
newURL.valueOf("fromDate")

Comment: Though the question is three years old, even today the check `URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString)` is pointless and will never fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way you can do it,

Your URL extension here, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421686/get-the-value-of-url-parameters)

```
extension URL {
    func valueOf(_ queryParamaterName: String) -> String? {
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) else { return nil }
        return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == queryParamaterName })?.value
    }
}
```

Your code goes here,

```
let string = "http://aa.no-ip.biz:8001/hf_tracker/api/history.php?accesskey=12345&Vehilce=1618&FromDate=2018-05-10 13:11&ToDate=2018-05-14 12:11"
let test = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let url = URL(string: test!)!
let fromDate = url.valueOf("FromDate")
let toDate = url.valueOf("ToDate")

let date1 = fromDate?.components(separatedBy: " ").first
print(date1)

let date2 = toDate?.components(separatedBy: " ").first
print(date2 )
```

Output will be below,

```
2018-05-10
2018-05-14
```

Answer (score 2):

In my apps a use a helper function that parses the url and returns an optional dictionary:

```
func parameters(for url: URL) -> [String: String]? {
    guard let urlQuery = url.query else { return nil }

    // Create all parameters dictionary
    let queryArray = urlQuery.split { $0 == "&" }.map(String.init)
    var parametersDict: [String: String] = [:]
    for queryParameter in queryArray {
        // split the queryParam into key / value
        let keyValueArray = queryParameter.split{ $0 == "=" }.map(String.init)
        let key = keyValueArray.first!
        let value = keyValueArray.last!.removingPercentEncoding!
        parametersDict.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
    }

    return parametersDict
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let params = parameters(for: URL(string: "https://someurl.com?name=john")!)
if let name = params?["name"] {
    print(name)
}
```

Or you can add a var to `URL` extension:

```
extension URL {
    var parameters: [String: String]? {
        guard let urlQuery = self.query else { return nil }

        // Create all parameters dictionary
        let queryArray = urlQuery.split { $0 == "&" }.map(String.init)
        var parametersDict: [String: String] = [:]
        for queryParameter in queryArray {
            // split the queryParam into key / value
            let keyValueArray = queryParameter.split{ $0 == "=" }.map(String.init)
            let key = keyValueArray.first!
            let value = keyValueArray.last!.removingPercentEncoding!
            parametersDict.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        }

        return parametersDict
    }
}
```

And get the parameter:

```
let params = URL(string: "https://someurl.com?name=john")!.parameters
if let name = params?["name"] {
    print(name)
}
```