# Get Value of URL Parameters

Tags: ios, swift, url

I'm trying to get the parameters from a URL using Swift. Let's say I have the following URL:

`https://test.page.link/foo?accessCode=GA362078&bar=test`

How can I get the value of `foo?accessCode` (GA362078), and `bar` (test)?

Comment: You can get all the parts of an URL using `NSURLComponents`. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents?language=swift

Comment: The URL Components returned will be ["/", "foo"].
Where I'm stuck is that I need to be able to get the value from foo?accessCode= and &bar=

Comment: I believe they are in `queryItems`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421686/get-the-value-of-url-parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756683/best-way-to-parse-url-string-to-get-values-for-keys etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `queryItems` of `URLComponents`:

```
func value(for name: String, in urlString: String, with path: String) -> String? {
    if let components = URLComponents.init(string: urlString) {
        if components.path == path {
            return components.queryItems?.first { $0.name == name }?.value
        }
        else {
            return("Not found")
        }
    }

    return nil
}

let urlString  = "https://test.page.link/foo?accessCode=GA362078&bar=test"

if let accessCodeValue = value(for: "accessCode", in: urlString, with: "/foo") {
    print(accessCodeValue)
}
```

Output:

```
GA362078
```

Comment: What about using `URLComponents` instead of `NSURLComponents` in recent Swift?

Comment: Is there a way to pass "foo" in a method parameter to return "GA362078" while also being able to pass in "bar" to get "test"?

Comment: @Han just get the QueryItem properties (name  `items[0].name` and value  `items[0].value`). Btw `/foo` is the path not a query item

Comment: I guess ideally I would like to look for the foo path and retrieve the following accessCode query item with its value

Comment: @Han: see update in my answer

Comment: @koen just return `first {$0.name == name }?.value`

Comment: @LeoDabus - thanks, and I guess that one liner can even just go in the main function, no need for an extension?

Comment: This is up to you. I like using extensions to avoid duplicating code but as you said it is just one line.